# Hyperlink in excel not redirecting to correct page

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have reviewed a similar question that was asked previously on here but couldn't find my answer.

I am hyperlinking to http://uk.eurosport.yahoo.com/fantasy/premier-league/details/39215 from a cell in Excel, but it is taking me to http://uk.eurosport.yahoo.com/fantasy/premier-league/ which is a sub page.  I am using Chrome, deleted cache and tried IE and Firefox, but without success.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Arjan Your solution from the linked answer suggests a cookie is missing. But since the OP said "tried IE and Firefox" (and chrome) wouldn't this mean he should have that cookie? Just curious

Comment: @nixda, I'm not sure what the OP means with that. (Did they set all these browsers as their default browser? Did they first open the link in the browser and then click the link in Excel, or the other way around? Does the specific link even work in all those browsers? Did they have to log in first?) But indeed, on OLD versions cookies between Internet Explorer and Excel were shared, assuming the browser was not closed. I am not sure if cookies are still shared for more recent versions. If it's not a matter of cookies, then the other answers in the duplicate cover that too, I feel.

Answer (score 0):

Requests to the first URL are redirected to the second by the remote webserver:

```
$ curl -I http://uk.eurosport.yahoo.com/fantasy/premier-league/details/39215
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Age: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2013 13:47:44 GMT
Location: /fantasy/premier-league/     <-- here
```

Perhaps the server is expecting a cookie to be provided by the browser, and redirects if it's not found.  Whatever the reason, this is why you're seeing the wrong URL when you click on your link.